# How to pass constructor arguments using Mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I want to mock a class using the Mockito framework, that has a couple of constructor arguments.

How would i go about passing those constructor arguments without generating setters for the private member variables ?

Thanks

Comment: If you're mocking a collaborator, why do you care about how it was constructed? You really only need to define how it interacts with the class under test.

Comment: @millhouse A member method i don't want to mock makes use of those member variables.

Comment: If you are unit testing a class, then you just mock the collaborators as @millhouse said. Otherwise you want to create a partial mock of your collaborator, which doesn't really make sense in your case. Anyway if you have some code snippet to show it could help.

Answer (score 4):

You said you want to mock some but not all of the methods.  I'm not sure why you'd want to do this - if your class is a collaborator, then it would make sense to mock the whole class.  Or if it's the SUT, you probably don't want to mock it at all.

It's possible that what you're looking for is a [spy](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13), rather than a mock.  If you decide to use a spy, you'll make it from a real object, which has already been constructed using whatever arguments you need it to be constructed from.

But before you consider using a spy, I urge you to think more carefully about exactly what it is that you're testing, and why you think you need to replace *some* of your methods with mock implementations, but not others.